# MVC 3 Form issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have just migrated my application from MVC2 to MVC3

And i found that whenever my login page is loaded the Action attribute remains **BLANK**

Following is the code :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateUser", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formLogin", name = "formLogin" }))
   { %>;

  ........

<%}%>;
```

in Browser it shows like following :

```
<form name="formLogin" method="post" id="formLogin" action="">

........


</form>
```

where Action is EMPTY

Please help me in this issue

Thanks,

Manoj

Comment: Could you show your routing definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a default route in the Global.asax.cs? BeginForm uses UrlHelper.GenerateUrl to match up the action/controller names to your route collection. So if you don't have a route that maps to ValidateUser, then it can't generate a URL for it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will need to write like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="myform"}))
  {
      some code here
  }
```